# 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'replace'

Tags: flask, upload

I'm using flask to make a web to upload videos, adding a video worked but when I try to edit(replace) the video I uploaded, there's a `AttributeError: 'SpooledTemporaryFile' object has no attribute 'replace'`

In `forms.py`, url as the route of the video:

```
url = FileField(
    label="Video",
    validators=[
        Optional()
    ],
    description="Video"
```

In `views,py`:

```
def movie_edit(id=None):
    form = MovieForm()
    form.url.validators = []
    movie = Movie.query.get_or_404(int(id))
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        data = form.data
        if not os.path.exists(app.config["UP_DIR"]):
            os.makedirs(app.config["UP_DIR"])
            os.chmod(app.config["UP_DIR"], "rw")
        if data["url"] != "":
            file_url = secure_filename(data["url"])
            movie.url = change_filename(file_url)
            form.url.data.save(app.config["UP_DIR"] + movie.url)
```

How to fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that `data["url"]` is a `SpooledTemporaryFile` object, not a string. Without the full stacktrace, I can't tell which line is barfing, but you probably need to change `file_url = secure_filename(data["url"])` to `file_url = secure_filename(data["url"].filename)` or something similar.

Comment: `.filename` is correct. https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/patterns/fileuploads/